# How to deal with this: SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server

Tags: selenium, android-studio, testing, intellij-idea, appium

guys I'm very new to Appium and testing in general but I'm learning. I'm facing this error and I don't know what to do with it honestly. I would highly appreciate it if you can help, please.

I am trying to test this application on my android studio emulator. The application is from GitHub (uni project)

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.1.0', revision: '87802e897b'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-N4P7Q2SH', ip: , os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {platformName: android}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appActivity: org.nearbyshops.whitelabela..., appPackage: org.nearbyshops.whitelabelapp, deviceName: emulator-5554, platformName: android}}]
Capabilities {}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:230)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:151)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:99)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:97)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake$Result org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient, org.openqa.selenium.remote.Command)'
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:225)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 8 more
```

Here's my code

```
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {


        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,  "emulator-5554");
        dc.setCapability("platformName", "android" );
        dc.setCapability("appPackage", "org.nearbyshops.whitelabelapp" );
        dc.setCapability("appActivity", "org.nearbyshops.whitelabelapp.LaunchActivity" );

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> ad = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("https://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),dc);

        MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.LinearLayout[3]/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ImageView");
        el1.click();
        MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView[1]");
        el2.click();
        MobileElement el3 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ImageView[3]");
        el3.click();
        MobileElement el4 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ImageView[3]");
        el4.click();
        MobileElement el5 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[4]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ImageView[1]");
        el5.click();
        MobileElement el6 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ImageView[3]");
        el6.click();
        MobileElement el7 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementById("org.nearbyshops.whitelabelapp:id/item_count");
        el7.click();

        Assert.assertEquals(ad.findElementById("org.nearbyshops.whitelabelapp:id/item_count").getText(),1);

    }
    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following capabilities to set up your android driver capabilities with added changes as below,

1. Added `MobileCapabilityType.VERSION` and add value of your real android device android version,
2. Added url with `http` and removed 'https' with final changes as, `http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub`

Please refer to the below capabilities working fine as,

```
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "11");
    dc.setCapability("platformName", "android");
    dc.setCapability("appPackage", "org.nearbyshops.whitelabelapp");
    dc.setCapability("appActivity", "org.nearbyshops.whitelabelapp.LaunchActivity");
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> ad = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great <3